# How to make Stamen's Toner labels bigger in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, quickmapservices

When I zoom in on my basemap that includes an overlay of Stamen's Toner labels from the QuickMapServices plug in.

Looks like this: (I need bigger street labels!)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Tiles are pre-rendered, you can't change them on your own.

You may go to https://github.com/stamen/toner-carto, make a private copy, change the style to fit your needs and render your own tiles.